# Cleaning up resources

Tags: c#, com, interop

Am trying to clean up resources in my C# code.

Here is the code:

```
finally
{
object[] myarray = new object[5] { globalRelation, asset, surfaceRelationNew, termStructureSlice,   equipRelation };

CleanupResource(myarray);
}


private void CleanupResource(params object[] objs)
{
          for (int count = 0; count < objs.Length; count++)
                {
                    if (objs[count] != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objs[count]);
                    }

                }
}
```

Is this is a good approach?
Or shall I call CleanupResource() method for each object rather than passing an array and then looping thru it.

Please suggest.

Comment: Trust the garbage collector.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are these unmanaged resource?

```
globalRelation, asset, surfaceRelationNew, termStructureSlice,   equipRelation
```

if no , then no need to worry about let CLR handel this

if this Unmanaged resources than i would say ypu are doing it correctly but why are you calling seperate method , just release in finally block

or

you can write class destructor if its okie to release it when object of your class GCed like below.

```
~MyClass()
{
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(globalRelation);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(asset);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(surfaceRelationNew);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(termStructureSlice);
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(equipRelation);
 }
```